# OrientDb check if edge exists

Tags: sql, graph, orientdb

In OrientDB Studio I am trying to write a function to check if an edge exists between two vertices. If the query finds a hit, it should return true, if there is no hit it should return false. Each vertex has a unique url within an embeddedSet. This is the field used to ID the vertex.

How to query for the edge? How to return true or false edge exist?

This code works, if I know the RID.

```
select from E where (in = #14:29 and out = #15:15) OR (in = #15:15 and out = #14:29);
```

This code works as long as the urlSet field is NOT a url.

```
select from E where out IN (select from v where urlSet contains 'A') and in IN (select from v where urlSet contains 'B');
```

When I try to search for the url's using this code

```
select from E where out IN (select from v where urlSet contains 'https:\/\/url1.com/a/something') and in IN (select from v where urlSet contains 'https:\/\/url2.com/b/something');
```

I receive this error:

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #35: Invalid keyword 'FROM' Command: select from E where out IN (select from v where urlSet contains 'https://url1.com/a/something') and in IN (select from v where urlSet contains 'https://url2.com/b/something'); -------------------------------------------^

Comment: which OrientDB version are you using?

Comment: You escape the first both **slashes** but not the others? Any reason for?

Comment: I am using OrientDB 2.0. When I run queries only the double slashes need to be escaped, I am going to escape all slashes from now on.